# Screen flickering on Lenovo laptop

Tags: graphics, screen, amd-graphics

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Lenovo V145-15AST laptop. Every so often the screen flickers and it is quite annoying because you cannot work. I have it in dual boot with Windows.